# Find out currentid next row from current id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select next row from current id.
**How can i find out my current id?**

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT performerid,pic0 FROM ".$table." WHERE id > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select it?

`$qry = mysql_query("SELECT id,performerid,pic0 FROM ".$table." WHERE id > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't work with any concept of current ID. If you're looking for the last inserted ID then it can be done via [mysql_inserted_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function.